# More efficient way of assigning values in DataTable?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable with two columns: JobDetailID and CalculatedID. JobDetailID is not always unique. I want one/the first instance of CalculatedID for a given JobDetailID to be JobDetailID + "A", and when there are multiple rows with the same JobDetailID, I want successive rows to be JobDetailID + "B", "C", etc. There aren't more than four or five rows with the same JobDetailID.

I currently have it implemented as follows, but it's unacceptably slow:

```
private void AddCalculatedID(DataTable data)
{
    var calculatedIDColumn = new DataColumn { DataType = typeof(string), ColumnName = "CalculatedID" };
    data.Columns.Add(calculatedIDColumn);
    data.Columns["CalculatedID"].SetOrdinal(0);

    var enumerableData = data.AsEnumerable();

    foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
    {
        var jobDetailID = row["JobDetailID"].ToString();

        // Give calculated ID of JobDetailID + A, B, C, etc. for multiple rows with same JobDetailID
        int x = 65; // ASCII value for A
        string calculatedID = jobDetailID + (char)x;

        while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["CalculatedID"].ToString()))
        {
            if ((enumerableData
                .Any(r => r.Field<string>("CalculatedID") == calculatedID)))
            {
                calculatedID = jobDetailID + (char)x;
                x++;
            }
            else
            {
                row["CalculatedID"] = calculatedID;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming I need to adhere to this format of output, how might I improve this performance?

Comment: Is it possible to do the calculation in the proc where you're getting the data?  May not be the most elegant solution, but you're looping through your result set to add a column.  Maybe it's better to do the calc in the proc and then avoid this code above.  Maybe a better first question is -- how are you getting the data?

Comment: How are you populating the `DataTable` in the first place? If it's out of a database I'd recommend calculating this column there.

Comment: The answer from @SPFiredrake is very readable (which I normally prefer over non-critical performance), but it's not "the fastest". Let me work in a faster method and put it as proposed answer.

Comment: I've just put what I consider a "faster" version, which still has room for optimization based on requirements yet to discover. Although, this doesn't use LINQ at all (which is good, it's faster to use custom code if you already know the required logic)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to add the code for generation of CalculatedID in the place where you are getting the data, but, if that is unavailable, you might want to avoid scanning the entire table each time a duplicate is found. You could use a `Dictionary` for the used keys, like this:

```
private void AddCalculatedID(DataTable data)
{
    var calculatedIDColumn = new DataColumn { DataType = typeof(string), ColumnName = "CalculatedID" };
    data.Columns.Add(calculatedIDColumn);
    data.Columns["CalculatedID"].SetOrdinal(0);

    Dictionary<string, string> UsedKeyIndex = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
    {
        string jobDetailID = row["JobDetailID"].ToString();
        string calculatedID;

        if (UsedKeyIndex.ContainsKey(jobDetailID))
        {
          calculatedID = jobDetailID + 'A';
          UsedKeyIndex.Add(jobDetailID, 'A');
        }
        else
        {
           char nextKey = UsedKeyIndex[jobDetailID].Value+1;
           calculatedID = jobDetailID + nextKey;
           UsedKeyIndex[jobDetailID] = nextKey;
        }

        row["CalculatedID"] = calculatedID;
    }
}
```

This will essentially trade memory for speed, as it will cache all used JobDetailID's along with the last char used for the generated key. If you have lots and lots of these JobDetailID, this might get a bit memory intensive, but I doubt that you'll have problems unless you have millions of rows to process.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your idea about setting CalculatedID for the rows, then following algorithm would do the trick and it's complexity is linear. Most important part is `data.Select("","JobDetailID")`, where I get a sorted list of rows. 
I didn't compiled it myself, so there could be syntactical errors.

```
private void AddCalculatedID(DataTable data)
{
    var calculatedIDColumn = new DataColumn { DataType = typeof(string), ColumnName = "CalculatedID" };
    data.Columns.Add(calculatedIDColumn);
    data.Columns["CalculatedID"].SetOrdinal(0);

    int jobDetailID = -1;
    int letter = 65;
    foreach (DataRow row in data.Select("","JobDetailID"))
    {
        if((int)row["JobDetailID"] == jobDetailID)
        {
            row["CalculatedID"] = row["JobDetailID"].ToString() + (char)letter;
            letter++;
        }
        else
        {
            letter = 65;
            jobDetailID = (int)row["JobDetailID"];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this as LINQ, but you are using iterative methods. Probably the best way to do this would be to use a combination of both, iterating over each "grouping" and assigning the calculated ID for each row in the grouping.

```
foreach (var groupRows in data.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(d => d["JobDetailID"].ToString()))
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupRows.Key))
        continue;

    // We now have each "grouping" of duplicate JobDetailIDs.
    int x = 65; // ASCII value for A
    foreach (var duplicate in groupRows)
    {
        string calcID = groupRows.Key + ((char)x++);
        duplicate["CalculatedID"] = calcID;
        //Can also do this and achieve same results.
        //duplicate["CalculatedID"] = groupRows.Key + ((char)x++);
    }
}
```

First thing you do is group on the column that's going to have duplicates. You're going to iterate over each of these groupings, and reset the suffix value for every grouping. For every row in the grouping, you're going to get the calculated ID (incrementing the suffix value at the same time) and assign the ID back to the duplicate row. As a side note, we're altering the items we're enumerating here, which is normally a bad thing. However, we're changing data that isn't associated with our enumeration declaration (GroupBy), so it will not alter the behavior of our enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

This method gets the job done in a single pass. You can optimize it further if, for example, "JobDetailID" is an integer instead of a string, or if the DataTable is always receiving the data sorted by "JobDetailID" (you could get rid of the dictionary), but here's a draft:

```
    private static void AddCalculatedID(DataTable data)
    {
        data.BeginLoadData();

        try
        {
            var calculatedIDColumn = new DataColumn { DataType = typeof(string), ColumnName = "CalculatedID" };
            data.Columns.Add(calculatedIDColumn);
            data.Columns["CalculatedID"].SetOrdinal(0);

            var jobDetails = new Dictionary<string, int>(data.Rows.Count);

            foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
            {
                var jobDetailID = row["JobDetailID"].ToString();
                int lastSuffix;

                if (jobDetails.TryGetValue(jobDetailID, out lastSuffix))
                {
                    lastSuffix++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // ASCII value for A
                    lastSuffix = 65;
                }

                row["CalculatedID"] = jobDetailID + (char)lastSuffix;
                jobDetails[jobDetailID] = lastSuffix;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            data.EndLoadData();
        }
    }
```